# Fibonnaci sequence java with limit value

Tags: java, for-loop, fibonacci

I need help with my java-program. This program is supposed to ask for the highest value fibonacci can have, and print out the number of series up to that value, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("The largest number fibonacci can be: ");
        int number = in.nextInt();
        if (number < 0){
            System.out.println("Wrong! Max-value has to be at least 0.");
        }
        int i;
        int f0 = 0;
        int f1 = 1;
        int fn;
        int value=0;
        for (i = 0; i<=value; i++){
            fn = f0 + f1;
            System.out.println("Fibonacci-number " + i + " = " + f0);
            f0 = f1;
            f1 = fn;
            value = number - f0;
        }
    }
}
```

If i put in `number = 12`, the program is supposed to print:

```
fibonacci-number 0 = 0 

...

fibonnaci-number 12 = 144
```

Comment: "[...] but it doesn't work" => This is not an adequate problem description. Please tell us what you expect, and what happens instead. As your program asks the user for input, please tell us also what input values you are testing with. And - last but not least - start to learn how to [debug a Java program](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html).

Comment: I don't understand your `for` loop, `for (i = 0; i<=value; i++)`, it will only run once so what is the point of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In java, how would I find the nth Fibonacci number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021102/in-java-how-would-i-find-the-nth-fibonacci-number)

Comment: @smoggers look more closely, you'll see that 'value' is changed later. That said, I'm not sure this for loop is correctly specified. Isn't it supposed to continue running until value reaches a certain number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the loop to compare value of increment-er (i) to 'number ' variable

```
for (i = 0; i<=number; i++){
//.........
}
```

Also use double instead of int if you want to print higher number in the series correctly.

There is no use of the 'value' variable.

Also, the phrase 'the highest value fibonacci can have' is misleading.You have mentioned number denotes number of terms in the series in your example.

If you want 'number' to be the highest value in the series, use following approach,

```
do{

        fn = f0 + f1;
        System.out.println("Fibonnaci-tall " + i + " = " + f0);
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = fn;
        i++;

}while(f0<=number);
```

Comment: If i do that, the program will print upto the sequence of the number i put in, but not the value like it's supposed to.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int f0 = 0;
int f1 = 1;
int fn = 0;

System.out.println("The largest number fibonnaci can be: ");
System.out.println("Input your number: ");
int number = in.nextInt();

if (number < 0){
    System.out.println("Wrong! Max-value has to be at least 0.");
} else {
    System.out.println(f0);
    System.out.println(f1);
    while (fn < number){
        fn = f0 + f1;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = fn;
        if (fn < number){
            System.out.println(fn);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No, not quite. If i put number = 144, the program only prints up to 89 when it's supposed to print upto 144.

Comment: So you want the sequence to continue until you reach 144? Then put while (fn != number). Otherwise, I'm not sure you get how the fibonacci sequence works.

Comment: indeed, replace the if statement with this if (fn <= number){
                System.out.println(fn);
            }

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCjz2.png)

Use this program, it will solve your query.

Comment: Thank you for adding another answer in which you copy-paste the code, instead of the snapshot. But please remove this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...It works!

```
 public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("The largest number fibonacci can be: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    if (number < 0){
        System.out.println("Wrong! Max-value has to be at least 0.");
    }
    else{
    int i=0;
    int f0 = 0;
    int f1 = 1;
    int fn;
    int value=0;
   do{
    //for (i = 0; i<=value; i++){
        fn = f0 + f1;
        System.out.println("Fibonacci-number " + i + " = " + f0);
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = fn;
        value = number - f0;
        i++;
    }while(f0<=number);
}//else
}
```